# How to make a ms form accessible for Teams meet attendees only

Tags: integration, microsoft-teams, ms-forms

Good day everyone

I am looking for a solution to give a ms form access to a teams meet attendees only.
Currently i am copying the MS Forms link and pasting it in to teams chat.
But since the form is public ( using attendees outside form org)  any attendee can copy and share the link to others.

I tried to embed through an iframe used the code option in the text editor of teams chat, but its not showing.
Any one can any alternative ideas to fulfill this requirement?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't a direct way to restrict the Microsoft Forms access to only the Teams meeting attendees.

Comment: To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).